# How to disable a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm able to disable a text area field of my form its working in google chrome but not working in internet explorer
can anyone help out in resolving this issue?Thanks in advance.

```js
$(".ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field").addClass("ms-rteflags-0");
```

```css
.ms-rteflags-0 {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field" id="Questions_8380cd28-f9ed-4f03-8105-4c3e4a018a1c_$TextField_inplacerte" style="min-height:84px" aria-labelledby="Questions_8380cd28-f9ed-4f03-8105-4c3e4a018a1c_$TextField_inplacerte_label"
  contenteditable="true" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true">
  <div class="ExternalClass4A270609CC8C4299B335846BABB3A4E0">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working in internet explorer.. update your browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prop` in jquery

```js
$('#txtArea').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtArea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```js
$('#textarea-id').prop('disabled', true);
```

Also, the selector you are using in your javascript snippet is wrong.

```js
$('.ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field').addClass('ms-rteflags-0');
```

The element you are trying to target has all classnames. So use this instead:

```js
$('.ms-rtestate-write.ms-rteflags-0.ms-rtestate-field').addClass("ms-rteflags-0");
```

(notice the dots)

Comment: hey its working fine for chrome but still its not working for internet explorer @Public Jorn

Comment: Well jquery 1.7.1 *is* compatible with IE. And using [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is the way to go. Can you confirm the textarea is not editable?
If it's just the styling that doesn't work, it might be because `opacity` is not fully supported by IE < 8. Try adding this to your `.ms-rteflags-0` class:
`filter: alpha(opacity=40);`